# Executing Host commands using PLSQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

We wanted to know if we execute unix host commands from PLSQL program.

Does this invoke host commands in oracle DB installed OS or we can invoke host commands for different servers? Please suggest.

Have not tried any solution, need suggestions/inputs before implementation.

**edit**

Our requirement is like we have an application that has app layer and database layer. App layer contains application related programs which interact with database layer for any database information. App layer and database layer reside in different hosts (different ip addresses). Application related programs are unix shell scripts that interact with file system.

Client requirement is that instead of shell script interacting with file system, PL/SQL code should do the work so that we have complete security.

Solutions suggested by Xing and Ozhan are in direction of Java code interacting with file system and providing the related information. Filesystem interaction is done using the `host` command program in Java. My question is if we run the host commands using java program in app layer will it connect to file system of app layer or will it connect to file system of database layer? We want file system layer of the client system connected, not the database server.

Hope I have articulate my requirement. Please let me know if you need any other info.

Comment: [this](https://oracle-base.com/articles/8i/shell-commands-from-plsql) might help.

Comment: This has what you are looking for https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:16212348050

Comment: Hi Ozhan and Zing, Thanks for your solution/options. My question is like if we issue host command whether it connects to local machine or database unix machine. Please let me know Regards, Prasad

Comment: PL/SQL runs on the database server. Consequently a `host` command issued in PL/SQL (by Java `Command`, DBMS_SCHEDULER or whatever) will execute on **the database server**.

Comment: For what it's worth your client's requirement seems a bit mad. Executing OS commands from the database entails granting OS privileges to the database, which is always risky (so easy to open backdoors if we're not careful). The weakening of security is much greater if you allow the database server to execute OS commands on a different server. So, are you sure you have correctly understood what they are asking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is yes and no

YES -> using sqlplus you can run host command from the machine you connect from.
NO -> when using utl packages it always redirects to the db machine/server

eg:

after connecting from sqlplus from windows/linux from local machine; you can do this

host mkdir abcd

host ls *.log

Comment: Hi Nizamudeen, thanks for your response. i understood the point. one small info..so if i use host commands encapsulated in java code as suggested above by Xing and Ozhan, where will i be connected to.. whether it would db machine/server or the local calling machine.? Please let me know

Comment: 1. host command can only be executed by the executable "sqlplus"  installed locally/client; it will not be recognized when you run sql code inside java

2. when you embed java code inside a plsql procedure; it will run host level commands (using java or plsql ) in the db server and not the client/local

3. if you could give an example of what you are trying to implement; may be i can give more details in that direction

Comment: Hi Nizamudeen, 
Thanks for your response.Our requirement is like we have application that has app layer and database (db) layer.app layer contains application related programs which interact to database layer for any db information.app layer and database (db) layer reside in different hosts (different ip addresses).application related programs are unix shell scripts that interact with file system.Client requirement is that instead of shell script interacting with file system,plsql code should the work so that we have complete security.

Comment: Solutions provided by Xing and Ozhan are in direction of java code interacting with file system and providing the relaed information.
filesystem interaction is done using the host command program in java.
My question is if we run the host commands using java program in app layer will it connect to file system of app layer or will it connect to file system of db layer.
We want file system layer of the client system connected not the db server.
Hope i could articulate my requirement.Please let me know if you need any other info.Regards,
Prasad S Billahalli

Comment: Hi Nizamudeen.. Please refer above 2 statement together as we have limited space.  Regards, Prasad S Billahalli

Comment: Good; in that case. What are all the host commands being executed from the OS layer and which is/are fed to the db-table  as inputs or vice versa ?

Comment: hi nizam,basic commands like cp,mv,ls, ls-lrt, etc which are available in /bin/* 
Our question is if i write java programs as given by Zing and Ozhan, executing the host commands in the app system.
Will it retrieve the app system's file system information or DB file system information.
Can you please let me know? Regards, Prasad

Comment: hi., using shell script or java io from client machine will execute and provide client host information only.

Answer (score -1):

Strictly speaking, you can't execute host commands from PL/SQL.

Comment: Hi Zeic..We can execute host commands through PLSQL.. can you please elaborate what you meant by strictly speaking regards